# Alternative to Bootstrap Affix

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar, affix

Been working with Bootstrap for a little bit, but am working without it on a new project.

Was curious whether anyone knew of an alternative, easy-to-use plugin to Bootstrap's 'affix'.

I'm really just looking for an element to go to `position:fixed` upon a certain scroll point (ideally defined by an element), stop at a particular scroll point (ideally defined by a page footer).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [jquery stickem](https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-Stickem) plugin? As stated in their README

> Make items sticky as you scroll, to a point.